# Android YouTubePlayer SDK API onFullScreen callback cause RecyclerView ViewHolder detached

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

**Device Info**

```
Android Device: HUAWEI COL_AL10
Android Version: Android 9
```

**Background**

I develop an Android app to play YouTube video by YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar, I choose native YouTube API instead of iFrame API.

**Produce**

Here is a Vertical-RecyclerView to display some YouTube Videos. I click the recyclerView's item and the video inside is to play, it's fine now.

Since I want to watch the YouTube Video in fullscreen mode, then I click the fullscreen button, trouble comes:

[image]

[image]

**Summary**

As soon as the fullscreen button clicked, the video playing ViewHolder in RecyclerView is detached and YouTube Player is released since the ViewHolder is removed or invalid said the RecyclerView. 
However, my Activity is already landscape since YouTube fullscreen button clicked just now.

Why and how to fix?

Any suggestion will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

guys

I finally solved the problem by code below:

```
youTubePlayer.setFullscreenControlFlags(0);
```

and then invoke Activity.setRequestedOrientation manually in onFullScreen callback.

That's it